# Rpi3 connect multiple glove based flex sensors [Perhaps using MCP3008 / MCP3208 ADC] Problem

Tags: pi-3, i2c

we are making a glove based on 5 flex sensors. The problem we are facing is that flex sensor transmit data in analog version while Raspberry pi 3 receive only digital data.if we are using ADC converter it using a lot of ports which a single PI cannot accumulate
how can we connect 5 sensor on 1 raspberry pi with or without ADC
Help me out  Anything related to this would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have made some suggestions.  Please feel free to ask me newbie questions.  I will try to extend my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the popular MCP3208 ADC has 8 multiplexed channels.

So if you use SPI CE0, CE1, you can use 2 MCP3208 for 16 inputs.

The bad thing about MCP300x, MCP320x is that they don't have cheap modules around.  It is tedious, messy, and error prone to wire through-hole chips.

Luckily there are other ways to have many more than 16 inputs.  For example, if you prefer I2C, there are too many ADC modules for you to choose, from 12bit, 16bit to 24bit, usually up to 4 differential or 8 single ended input channels.

The I2C ADS1025 ADC moduel is getting popular.  You might like to check it out.

[AliExpress I2C ADS1015 16 Bit ADC 4 channel](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/I2C-ADS1115-ADS1015-16-Bit-ADC-4-channel-Module-with-Programmable-Gain-Amplifier-2-0V-to/32674556200.html?spm=a2g0w.10010108.1000016.1.55af10e32wuxFR&isOrigTitle=true)

For I2C there is a nice chip which can multiply your same address modules by 8.  In other words, you can have 8 I2C chips with the same device address, selected by software.  I know this sounds complicated.  But when you are running out of I2C addresses, then you will be eager to learn, and appreciate this I2C address multiplying chip.

[AliEexpress TCA9548A I2C 8 way multi channel expansion-board](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/CJMCU-9548-TCA9548A-1-to-8-I2C-8-way-multi-channel-expansion-board-IIC-module-development/32566064206.html?spm=a2g0w.10010108.1000016.1.ccca6514TVhvuF&isOrigTitle=true)

***References***

[MCP3208 8 Channel 12-Bit ADC with SPI Serial Interface](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf)